# How to have several tabs from the same layout, correctly handling edittext?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-orientation

I've got three tabs, all from a layout xml file,say list.xml. In list.xml I've defined a EditText, something like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/filterText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/filterClear"
    android:hint="@string/filterHint"
    android:text="@string/filter">
</EditText>
```

However, it seems that if doing a orientation change and having typed something into one of the three EditTexts (all I guess with the same ID), the text doesn't restore to the same state. Sometimes (depending on which tab I've typed into) all fields are empty or all fields are filled.

What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: Do they actually have the same ID? If so, change them to have different IDs. Android should save the text in each automatically when the `Activity` restarts on orientation change, provided they each have unique IDs.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this, retaining the XML, or would I have to create the same EditText programatically (I don't want to have 3 files with the exact same content, except the ID)? And why doesn't the Context resolve this? Although they have the same ID globally, they should be identifiable by their Context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having three separate layout files `list1.xml`, `list2.xml`, `list3.xml`, that only differed in the IDs. So `list1.xml` would have `@+id/filterText1`, `list2.xml` would have `@+id/filterText2` and so on.

And then in the `ListActivity.java` file I used to have this as part of my onCreate:

```
setContentView(R.layout.list);
```

And several references to this throughout the activity:

```
EditText filter = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.filterText);
```

...

Instead I have now got this in my onCreate:

```
if(START_TAB1.equals(startMode)) { // Checks which tab is being started
    setContentView(R.layout.list1); // Use appropriate layout
    filterTextId = R.id.filterText1; // Save correct ID in a class variable
}
// And then the same "else if..." for all other tabs
```

And this when referencing the field itself throughout the activity:

```
EditText filter = (EditText)findViewById(filterTextId); // Use common ID
```